# iPhoto 8 alternative

Tags: software-recommendation, photos.app

I kind of like iPhoto 8, but it's unmantained, is there an alternative that:

- runs on 10.6
- imports iPhoto library (events, albums, Facebook albums, hidden photos), and works more or less like iPhoto itself
- is actively mantained
- if it's not free, it offers an almost-fully working demo, i.e. limited in time but not in features (to be sure it actually works)
- if it's not free, it has a reasonable price (i.e. 5~15€)

My problem with iPhoto itself is that the newer version requires 10.7, and the version I'm using has some very annoying bugs, such as every time I click on a Facebook album, it resets its privacy to "friends only".

*(likely such a software doesn't exist, but searching for such a topic brings up such a mess that I'm not sure, it might be well hidden)*

If you know of a program which doesn't have all these features, but have *most* of them, feel free to list it anyway (no Picasa).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/)? It has built in support for importing from iPhoto libraries. Release notes for v. 3.9 [here](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/53209).

You may not want to join the Google universe, though. Resistance is futile.

Comment: I've tried to use Picasa a few times, and I've _always_ been _very_ disappointed. Terrible software IMHO. By the way, I use plenty of Google products (Gmail, Android, calendar, gtalk, groups, reader, etc.) so I can safely say I'm not exactly biased towards them ;)

Comment: Why the down vote 5 months later?